# SIGABRT doesn't generate core dumps in MacOS

Tags: c++, linux, macos, operating-system, coredump

In macOS, I find that SIGABRT won't generate core dumps in some cases.

For example, I run a sleep in one terminal:

```sh
lianxin.wlx@mbp [01:08:21] [~/test]
-> % sleep 1000
```

And send a SIGABRT to it in another terminal:

```sh
lianxin.wlx@mbp [01:08:59] [~]
-> % ps -ef | grep sleep
  502 47679 20388   0  1:08AM ttys001    0:00.01 sleep 1000
lianxin.wlx@mbp [01:09:03] [~]
-> % kill -6 47679
```

Then the sleep process is aborted, but no core dump is generated.

```sh
lianxin.wlx@mbp [01:08:21] [~/test]
-> % sleep 1000
[1]    47679 abort      sleep 1000
lianxin.wlx@mbp [01:10:35] [~/test]
-> % ls /cores
lianxin.wlx@mbp [01:10:37] [~/test]
-> %
```

So why? I've tested the same operations in Linux, it did generate a core dump.

I'm sure I've opened the core dump right(`ulimit -c unlimited`, and `/cores`'s privilege is 777). I wrote a program that will crash with SIGSEGV, and it did generate a core dump in /cores.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a simple program,

```
main() {
    abort();
}
```

It will generate a core dump if run with appropriate priv.
Also, if you make a:

```
main() {
    sleep(100);
}
```

run it in the background and kill -ABRT , it will generate a core dump.
But /bin/sleep doesn't, which is a bit odd.

This is assuming you have followed the recipe in `man core`.

Comment: I tried the second program, it won't generate core dumps. The first one will.

Comment: It does on my `Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Wed Apr 24 20:50:53 PDT 2019; root:xnu-3789.73.49~1/RELEASE_X86_64`  (Sierra).

Comment: mine is Darwin 20.6.0, MacOS BigSur 11.6 (20G165). Maybe it's related to the system version?

Comment: Does`man core` on your system shed any light?   I was a bit surprised I had to run it as root to get it generate a core file.